# remote log in to Windows

Tags: windows, remote-access, login

From a remote machine, is there an easy way to log into windows?  Maybe using psexec.exe or mstsc.exe?  This would be lauched by a script.

I know the username and password.  I only need this to work on Windows 7 and on 2008 R2.

Comment: What's the objective?

Comment: To expand on Chris_K's comment, the phrase "log into" is ambiguous in this context.  You need to explain what you want to happen.

Comment: I want the same thing that would happen if I connected to the machine, pressed Ctrl-Alt-Del and entered my username and password to log into windows as that user.

Comment: Given that you already name mstsc.exe - what the heck do you want to know? How to START mstsc? How to log into the other machine without it having remote desktop enabled? I dont see anything left after starting mstsc.exe that you already know.

Comment: You can save Remote Desktop settings into an .rdp file and then open it from the command line.  Type mstsc -? for the command-line syntax.

Comment: I think you should discuss this with your system administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP). Microsoft currently refers to their official RDP server software as Remote Desktop Services, formerly "Terminal Services". Their official client software is currently referred to as Remote Desktop Connection, formerly "Terminal Services Client".

You will need to enable the service on the target, but after that, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want "the same thing" as an interactive logon, you would need to do an interactive logon. mstsc would require you to enter the username and password, but you could simply save the credentials for the given context of your script.